# How can this scenario work with ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This scenario is really different, I want to make it but I could'nt find out how to do it. My scenario is like this:

I have One `ArrayList` and this `ArrayList` is always updating with new one. Please think like this.

LIST ONE is my target list. I have these items in this list:

**A
B
C**

I'm saving this list two time in first launch: `list_old_one`  -  `list_new_one`

After few minutes coming new items with old items.

**A
B
C
D**

And also I'm saving this list: `list_new_one`

I want to make this. If **C** does not exist to `list_one_now`, I want to show just this and I want to delete all other items and just show **C** not with **D**

I tired with `equal` and `removeAll` section but also coming item **D** because it's not equaling.

**My ArrayList:**

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());

//Adding current list to new one
tinydb.remove("list_new_one");
tinydb.putListString("list_new_one", all_list);

ArrayList<String> list_old = new ArrayList<>(tinydb.getListString("list_old_one"));
ArrayList<String> list_new = new ArrayList<>(tinydb.getListString("list_new_one"));

   list_old.removeAll(list_new);
   if (list_new.size() != 0) {
        //Adding results to database
        DBRecentlyHelper dbRecentlyHelper = new DBRecentlyHelper(getApplicationContext());
        dbRecentlyHelper.RecentlyADD(list_old, current_user);
        dbRecentlyHelper.close();

       //Updating old list
       tinydb.remove("list_old_one");
       tinydb.putListString("list_old_one", all_list);
  }else{
       //Updating old list
       tinydb.remove("list_old_one");
       tinydb.putListString("list_old_one", all_list);
  }
```

I'm really looking in one week but still I'm getting wrong results.

If anybody have idea, I'll be glad for it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Poor title. Please edit to reflect the specific technical issue of your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success answer is good way, but also the hard way. Because you do not need to get items. Android OS always can equal short or long texts.

**Replace:**

```
list_old.removeAll(list_new);
```

**To:**

```
for(String i: new ArrayList<>(list_old)) {
                for(String j: new ArrayList<>(list_new)) {
                    if (!i.equals(j)) {
                        list_old.add(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

You'll get correctly results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
myList.stream().filter(item -> item.equals("C")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Because the "D" item is not present in list_new, then removeAll cannot remove it. If you need to check if your list contains "C" item, you can do like this:

```
if(myList.contains("C")){myList = myList.stream().filter(item -> item.equals("C")).collect(Collectors.toList());}
```

You don't need to use two list to remove all others items.

Answer (score 0):

You get wrong list because you're equaling lists with lists. Do like this;

Create a SQLite like your SQLite `DBRecentlyHelper`. For Example: `DBOldListItems` and `DBOldListItems`

Save all items to new DB what I said and equal it item to item.

**OLD ITEMS:**

```
A - B - C
```

**NEW ITEMS:**

```
A - B - C - D
```

**Example:**

```
if(!olditems.get(i).item.equals(newitems.get(i)){
    olditems.get(i).item
}
```

If, A item will not equal with newitems array, you'll get the result. After results, you can update the your olditems and you can do this more, more, more.

If you could not understand anything, please contact with me. Maybe my english not understandable :)